# Jquery UI dialog inner html not showing

Tags: jquery, html, forms, jquery-ui

I want to insert a login form to a dialog. Now the dialog is showing but without the form ! Any help please ?
I looked on google and other posts on this site but I found no answer !

here is the code:

```js
$('.dia').attr('title', 'LOGIN').text('Login to eWarsha').dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  modal: true,
  draggable: false,
  resizable: false,
  width: 600,
  height: 400
});

$('#cl').click(function() {

  $('.dia').dialog("open");

});
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="submit" id="cl">
  <div class="dia">
    <form class="dia login-form-dia" method="post">
      <input type="text" id="si" name="leamil" placeholder="Email" maxlength="16">
      <input type="text" id="si" name="lpassword" placeholder="Password">
      <input type="submit" name="login" value="LOGIN">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're replacing the contents of the `.dia` element when you call the `.text()` method:

```
$('.dia').attr('title', 'LOGIN').text('Login to eWarsha').dialog({ ... });
```

It seems like you would rather prepend that text using the following instead:

```
$('.dia').attr('title', 'LOGIN').prepend('<h2>Login to eWarsha</h2>').dialog({ ... });
```

..you could just specify the `title` attribute in the HTML, and add the desired text there rather than prepending it too:

```js
var $dialog = $('.dia').dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  modal: true,
  draggable: false,
  resizable: false,
  width: 600,
  height: 400
});

$('#cl').click(function() {
  $dialog.dialog("open");
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="submit" id="cl">
  <div class="dia" title="LOGIN">
    <h2>Login to eWarsha</h2>
    <form class="login-form-dia" method="post">
      <input type="text" id="si" name="leamil" placeholder="Email" maxlength="16">
      <input type="text" id="si" name="lpassword" placeholder="Password">
      <input type="submit" name="login" value="LOGIN">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```